# GC real time significant longer

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The application is using -XX:+UseParallelGC. 
There was a GC and real time took significant longer time than the user + sys (~1.05 secs): 
[Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, **real=1.05 secs**]

The PSYoungGen for the previous GC were cleaning same amount of memory and much less time. I don't have any flag enable to check if jit caused this. There was load on the machine this was running but was caused from the same jvm process that did the GC.

What reasons could cause something like this and what can I do to in the future to figure it out what's happening (if it happens again)?

```
 [GC
Desired survivor size 720864 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 15)
 [PSYoungGen: 18864K->454K(21121K)] 38016K->17722K(64833K), 0.0224350 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=1.05 secs]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to diagnose this better in the future run with `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCCause` for more useful logs. Which JVM version you're using may also be relevant.

Beyond that you'll have to monitor system stats, mostly paging and CPU utilization to see whether other processes or disk IO starve the JVM.

Comment: will enable those flags for the next time